# Combining two tables using UNION ALL

Tags: sql

I have two tables with the same fields. I wish to combine these into one big table. Each table's primary key is a unique respondent id.

When I combine the two tables with a UNION ALL, some data gets put into the wrong fields! Why is this? They are in the correct fields in the original tables. Is UNION ALL the correct operator?

Answer (score 7):

The thing to remember about Unions is that the column names for the resulting dataset will be defined by the first table in the union declaration.

Additionally, the order they are found in the declaration for the structure of the table will be impactive in this.

if tableA is defined as Name, Address, Email while table B is defined as Name, Email, Address

```
select * from tableA
union all
select * from tableB
```

will put tableB.Email in a column aliased as 'Address' to correct this, you must define the columns in your select statement:

```
select Name, Email, Address from tableA
union all
select Name, Email Address from tableB
```

Comment: I think you said that I *must* be careful and make sure that each field is paired with the correct field. Is that correct? (I just discovered how to do this in Access. :)

By the way, how does UNION ALL differ from appending?

Comment: in Access, an APPEND statement, adds a record to the table. What a UNION ALL does is returns all the records from both tables as a single data result, and includes duplicates. This is opposed to just the UNION which returns a distinct set of the resulting data.

Comment: You can use either APPEND or UNION ALL to combine tables, then?

<br/>

So UNION combines tables and removes duplicates?

Comment: Not exactly. APPEND adds data to an existing table. UNION and UNION ALL create single data result sets from multiple select statements.

Answer (score 4):

UNION ALL should be the right operation, but did you list fields explicitely by name in both parts or did you use asterisk as wildcard?

Comment: I used asterisk as wildcard. I just learned today that I should pair each field and not use asterisk. :)